# PHP sorting results

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have code like this:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($persons as $key) : ?>
    <?php if($this->session->userdata('id_user') == $key['id_person'] ) : ?>
    <li><em><?php echo $key['name'] . " " . $key['surname'] ?></em></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><?php echo $key['name'] . " " . $key['surname'] ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

How can I place result from the if condition at the first place? Can I do here or I need to write SQL query?

EDIT:

This is output:

```
<ul>
<li>Marko Džunić</li>
<li><em>Saša Miljković</em></li>
<li>mirko mirkovic</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get this:

```
<ul>
<li><em>Saša Miljković</em></li>
<li>Marko Džunić</li>
<li>mirko mirkovic</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pardon? This question makes no sense. Please show the output you get at the moment and the output you want.

Comment: How to you get the $persons? do you store it in a database? more details please

Comment: I'd do some sorting/swapping in the controller, rather than trying to do this in your template layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $first = '';
        $content = '';
        $id_user = $this->session->userdata('id_user');    
    ?>
    <?php foreach($persons as $key) : ?>
    <?php
        $id_person = $key['id_person'];
        $name = $key['name'];
        $surname = $key['surname'];

        if ($id_user == $id_person)    
        {            
            $first = '<li><em>' . $name . ' ' . $surname . '</em></li>';
        }
        else
        {
            $content .= '<li>' . $name . ' ' . $surname . '</li>';
        }
    ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php echo $first, $content; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through your array two times.

1. The first time you only echo when the person is the selected person and then delete this person from the array by using unset().
2. Go through your array a second time like you did before.

The selected item is now the first item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to get the result sorted from the Mysql itself. In MySQL you can place particular rows at the top.